# Jquery tr id selection

Tags: jquery

We are having 2 problem with jquery. Please have a look at the following...

We are using following table:

```
<tr id="row-5">
  <td></td>
  <td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

And we are using following code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.delete').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: info,
            success: function () {}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

So our questions are...

1. How do we get the correct value of id(5) instead of row-5?
2. Should we use each function on jquery code? If yes, how do we do that?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

Re your comment below:

> i asked about each function because i am using jquery sortable and paging for 100 rows and delete button works great for first 10 rows but after that it changes url to #

That's because you're only hooking up the rows that *already exist* when the page is loaded. If you change your code to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `click`, it'll work with new ones added after:

```
$(function() {
    // Change is +--- here
    //           V
    $('.delete').live('click', function() {
        var id  = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
        id = id.substring(4); // or .split('-')[1] as suggested by other answer
        var info = 'id='+id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(){
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

`bind` (`click` is just a shortcut for `bind`) hooks up the handler to elements that *already exist*. When you use a paging plug-in, the other elements aren't there yet, so they won't get hooked up. `delegate` and `live` work differetly: They take advantage of *event bubbing* and hook the event on a container element (`live` uses the root of the document, `delegate` uses whatever you tell it to use). See the linked docs for details. If you can use `delegate` rooted in the container table, do that in preference to `live`.

---

**Original answer**:

`attr` is giving you the correct value ("row-5"). If you want to extract just the "5" from that, you can use `substring`:

```
id = id.substring(4);
```

I'm not seeing anywhere you'd need to loop.

---

**Off-topic**: You can also save the browser a bit of work by using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) rather than `parents`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.delete').click(function() {
        var id  = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
        var info = 'id='+id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(){
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: almost correct, you have to use `id.substr(3);` since the index starts at 0 and the substring function is called substr in js.

Comment: @ntziolis: JavaScript has both `substring` and `substr` (`substring` is from/to, `substr` is from/length). The "from" in both cases starts at zero, and so we want `4`, not `3`, in this case (because we want to start with the fifth, not fourth, character): http://jsbin.com/ekuhi4

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thx for the substring  hint, and yes you are right 4 is the correct index to start with, man my counting has been better once ;)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thanks for answer, i asked about each function because i am using jquery sortable and paging for 100 rows and delete button works great for first 10 rows but after that it changes url to #.

Comment: @seoppc: Ah, that's a different problem entirely. I'll post an update. Edit: Updated.

Answer (score 5):

1 - `var id  = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id").split("-")[1];`

2 - No need, since the row you are selecting is the closest parent row to the clicked anchor.

Comment: or just use `$(this).closest("tr").attr("id").substr(4);`

Comment: I favour the `split` approach because it's resilient to prefix change - not really a killer reason to use it, but it's just my preference.

Comment: thanks for answer, i asked about each function because i am using jquery sortable and paging for 100 rows and delete button works great for first 10 rows but after that it changes url to #.